# Python - Problems with a while loop

Tags: python, input, output

For my program I must enter a positive number, but if I enter a negative number I need the program to error with a message saying, "Please use a positive number and try again", then go back to the part where you input a number. It's stuck in a loop. Here's my code:

```
import math

# Receive the input number from the user
x = float(input("Enter a positive number: "))

#Initialize the tolerance and estimate
tolerance = 0.000001
estimate = 1.0

#Perform the successive approximations
while True:
    estimate = (estimate + x / estimate) / 2
    diference = abs(x - estimate ** 2)
    if diference <= tolerance:
       break
    elif x < 0:
        print("Please enter a positive number")
#Output the result
print("The program's estimate:", estimate)
print("Python's estimate:     ", math.sqrt(x))
```

Comment: Your question has been edited to remove your apologies about lack of experience; don't take this to mean that people don't care, it's just that in a public question-answer forum, it's easier for those who come after to read a question that does not include that stuff. Besides, all skill levels are welcome here; you don't need to justify your question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you need to re-request the user input inside of the while loop as others have already mentioned.

A more thorough version of this answer would also be to refactor the order of operations inside of the while loop. In the code you are running the math operations on `x` before you validate that it is greater than zero. If the math is known to fail without a positive integer you would have a bug in your code that could lead to an unhandled exception. Here is another version with switches the if statement so we check the input before doing anything else - which makes the program less likely to throw an exception based on the input.

```py
import math

#Initialize the tolerance and estimate
tolerance = 0.000001
estimate = 1.0

#Perform the successive approximations
while True:
    # Receive the input number from the user
    x = float(input("Please enter a positive number:"))
    if x <= tolerance:
        print("Invalid input.")
        continue
    else:
        estimate = (estimate + x / estimate) / 2
        diference = abs(x - estimate ** 2)
        break

#Output the result
print("The program's estimate:", estimate)
print("Python's estimate:     ", math.sqrt(x))
```

Comment: Thank you for doing what you do my friend. I appreciate you taking your time to go further into detail on my question. Really helps me understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by put your `input()` into `while` loop

```
import math

#Initialize the tolerance and estimate
tolerance = 0.000001
estimate = 1.0

while True:

    # Receive the input number from the user
    x = float(input("Enter a positive number: "))

    estimate = (estimate + x / estimate) / 2
    diference = abs(x - estimate ** 2)
    if diference <= tolerance:
       break
    elif x < 0:
        print("Please enter a positive number")
--snip--
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elif x < 0:
  print("Please enter a positive number") 
  # Receive the input number from the user
  x = float(input("Enter a positive number: "))
```

add the 4th line in your code. it will work. you were not receiving the input again after the fail attempt.